# Weak maximum principle for eliptic PDEs proof question

Tags: elliptic-equations

I have been given a proof for the weak maximum principle and I do not understand the logic in one of the steps.

Let $a_{ij}$ be syymetric then: $$Lv=\sum_{i,j=1}^N a_{ij}(x)\partial_{x_i}\partial_{x_j}+\sum_{i=1}^Nb_i(x)\partial_{x_i}v  $$ 
Then in one step of the proof we have that $\nabla v(x_0)=0$  and the Hessian matrix $\nabla^2 v(x_0)$ is negative semi-definite. So we have:
$$
Lv(x_0)=\sum_{i,j=1}^N a_{ij}(x_0)\partial_{x_i}\partial_{x_j}v(x_0)
$$
But the part I do not understand is the following line:

$$
\sum_{i,j=1}^N a_{ij}(x_0)\partial_{x_i}\partial_{x_j}v(x_0)=Trace(a(x_0)\nabla^2(v(x_0))
$$

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've realised the expression is essentially the definition of trace of the multiplication of two matrices. Let $B=(b_{ij})$ and $C=(c_{ij})$  be two $n\times n$ matrices. Then:
$$
Trace(AB)=
\begin{matrix}
b_{11}c_{11}+\dots+a_{n1}b_{n1}\\
\vdots
\\
+b_{1n}c_{n1}+\dots+a_{nn}b_{nn} 
\end{matrix}
=\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N b_{ij} c_{ij}
$$